# Heroku + Node: Cannot find module error

Tags: javascript, git, node.js, heroku, sequelize.js

My Node app is running fine locally, but has run into an error when deploying to Heroku. The app uses Sequelize in a `/models` folder, which contains `index.js`, `Company.js` and `Users.js`. Locally, I am able to import the models using the following code in `/models/index.js`:

```
// load models
var models = [
  'Company',
  'User'
];
models.forEach(function(model) {
  module.exports[model] = sequelize.import(__dirname + '/' + model);
});
```

This works fine, however, when I deploy to Heroku the app crashes with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/models/Company'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at module.exports.Sequelize.import (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:219:24)
   at module.exports.sequelize (/app/models/index.js:60:43)
   at Array.forEach (native)
   at Object.<anonymous> (/app/models/index.js:59:8)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
Process exited with status 8
```

Initially I thought it was due to case sensitivity (local mac vs heroku linux), but I moved the file, made a git commit, and then moved back and committed again to ensure `Company.js` is capitalized in the git repository. This didn't solve the problem and I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The problem was due to case sensitivity and file naming. Mac OS X is case insensitive (but aware) whereas Heroku is based on Linux and is case sensitive. By running `heroku run bash` from my terminal, I was able to see how the `/models` folder appeared on Heroku's file system. The solution was to rename `User.js` and `Company.js` on my local system to new temporary files, commit the changes to git, then rename back to `User.js` and `Company.js` being mindful of the capitalized first letter and then committing the changes again via git. Previously I had tried to rename the files directly from `user.js` to `User.js` and `company.js` to `Company.js` but the git commit and case-sensitive file name changes did not reflect on Heroku.

Comment: I had this same problem and had been trying to figure it out for the longest time. Thank you and than @dankohn!

Comment: YOU SIR ARE A FREAKING LEGEND. Had this wrong in the (auto generated) package.json file with „server.js“ instead of „Server.js“.

Comment: Bravo, this was just the ticket for me and my "Tools"/"tools" folder

Comment: Wow - Thank you - had no idea what was going on - I had misnamed my models User file with lower case user.js on my initial push to heroku and even though I corrected it later on - the file stayed lower case

Comment: this worked for me too I checked with Heroku run bash and my file was somehow capital and locally it was lowercase. thanks a lot

Comment: maybe usefull to say that you can always check with heroku run bash if the naming of the files is like expected

Comment: Thank you so much. I was importing a module with camel case when the file was not actually capitalized that way. My Mac did not complain - though it should have.

Answer (score 36):

I can't see the exact fix, but you can figure it out yourself by running `heroku run bash` to log into a Heroku instance, then run `node` to enter a REPL, and try requiring the paths directly.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful debugging tip which enabled me to fix the issue.

Comment: I never knew you could look at your heroku file structure - this has been a life saver - Thanks!!!

Comment: still valid in 2021

Comment: What key words in REPL should I type?

Answer (score 7):

For me, it was caused by a folder that I had accidentally included in .gitignore!

Answer (score 2):

I've been through an error like this one and the cause was that I renamed a module `module.js` to `Module.js` and the Heroku cache was conflicting the names. You must disable module caching to avoid this kind of error:

```sh
$ heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false
```

Source: https://help.heroku.com/TO64O3OG/cannot-find-module-in-node-js-at-runtime

Comment: This didn't work for me. If you are working on MacOS and changed the case of a file's name, the only solution that worked for me is the first one, i.e. rename the file into a temporary name that differs not only by the letter's case, and then change it back... Thought it's worth mentioning to save others the time of testing this (BTW cache is a good thing, and I wouldn't waive it that easily)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the same issue as described here, but for me my `require("dotenv").config()` was not conditioned upon the environment that the code was running in, thus Heroku could not find it since it was installed as a `devDependency`.

Fix:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require("dotenv").config();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my files had a lowercase name locally and it was required as a lowercase.

```
const Product = require('../models/product');
```

On the git repo it was capitalized.

```
'../models/Product'
```

The server was trying to require a file which did not exist. I had to use `git mv` to rename the file locally then reupload it to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just deleted the older app from Heroku and created the new one via Heroku web, and then pushed the code to the newer one, and then it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31189622)

Answer (score 0):

For me what I changed was:

- File name was CheckPermissions and I changed it to checkPermissions and then hosted. Error occurred.
- Then revert the changes and hosted. This time worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved using dockerizing my application.

1. Create dockerFile from node
2. set heroku stack as docker
3. Deploy

Ref : https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker