# Node Heroku Deploy Cannot Find Exported Mongo Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, heroku, deployment

The Heroku build process from my node app completes without issue, but when I attempt to access the deployed site the Heroku logs display following error:

```
2017-09-19T18:50:49.490021+00:00 app[web.1]: > simple-weather-app@0.0.0 start /app
2017-09-19T18:50:49.490022+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665027+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:487
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665042+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665043+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665045+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/location'
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665047+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665044+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665049+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/index.js:4:16)
2017-09-19T18:50:50.665050+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
```

The repo is available here: https://github.com/lgants/simple-weather-app. And, it works find locally. Any thoughts on what's causing this?

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341975/heroku-node-cannot-find-module-error) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get that to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the repository you sent, the file is capitalized as `Location.js` but you are calling for the file `../models/location`. Make sure to call exactly the file name, capitalized chars makes difference depending on the OS, that's why it works locally and not in Heroku.

Change it to `../models/Location.js`.