# Node.js server works locally but not on Heroku because of missing `cleanModifiedSubpaths`

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a simple node.js server started up by

```
http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

It works completely fine locally, but when I deploy to Heroku, the application crashes and in the error log, I receive the error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module './services/document/cleanModifiedSubpaths'
```

I have tried searching for this error, but I don't see anyone else with this problem.

What can have caused this?

Comment: its looking for `cleanModifiedSubpaths` inside `services/document` folder, does it exist?

Comment: No it doesn't. What should it contain?

Comment: I don't have much idea, but its one of the [`mangoose`](https://npmdoc.github.io/node-npmdoc-mongoose/build/apidoc.html) internal method.

Comment: Please show your package.json and project source files structure.

Comment: I would `npm update` Mongoose and Mongo. If it works locally, there's also a possibility some files are not being deployed to Heroku: check your version control, particularly branches and gitignore.

Comment: Please provide the git repo that you have used, there might be something in your code that you are missing

Comment: Make sure you push the package-lock.json file to your git if you are using the latest version of npm to avoid version incompatibility.Also, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19348043/4115895 which says the problem could be due to case sensitivity and file naming.

Comment: can you please be more detail on your question by providing the link to the repo on git so that we can see the package.json file and how the whole project is structured

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can find your solution below link, it looks casesensitive problem because heroku is based on linux hence application cant access the file.

[@surfearth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341975/heroku-node-cannot-find-module-error)